# Node express app - structuring unit / integration tests

Tags: node.js, express, tdd, mocha.js

I'm trying to set up my test suite for my nodejs / express application.

I have a structure similar to [this](https://github.com/madhums/node-express-mongoose-demo) example, where I have an app folder, within which are model, view, controller folders.

I have my test directory currently split as

- unit
- integration

Inside unit, I mimic the folder structure of app. 
I have unit tests around my modes etc... that save to a test mongodb instance

My question is, should I unit tests my controllers, or should I save that for integration testing?

My ‘controllers’ look like:

controllers/account.js

```
exports.login = function(req, res) {
     res.render('account/login', {
          title: 'Log In'
     });
};

exports.login_post = function(req, res, next) {
     passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
          if (err) {
               return next(err);
          }
          if (!user) {
               return res.redirect('/account/login');
          }
          req.logIn(user, function(err) {
               if (err) {                   
                    return next(err);
               }
               return res.redirect('/');
          });
     })(req, res, next);
};
```

Would it be better to test this by using supertest, across the whole stack, or by “unit” testing login_post for example?

Answer (score 0):

I will keep this for the integration tests. I'll also go with tools like [Phantom](http://phantomjs.org/) or [Dalekjs](http://dalekjs.com/). My experience shows me that it is better to test the actual rendered html, but following a specific user interaction flow. There are of course problems with this approach. In my case was the fact that I had to change the markup very often. This of course break the tests all the time.